# Método save do Spring Boot sobrescrevendo registro

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

O meu objetivo é pegar o registro de uma tabela chamada Membro através do ID e gravar esses registro em outra tabela chamada GrandeComissao.

Veja as tabelas em questão.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "membro")
public class Membro {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    private String senha;
```

E a tabela **GrandeComissao**.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grande_comissao")
public class GrandeComissao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String nome;

    private Integer voto;
```

Esse abaixo é o comportamento atual. Existem 3 registros na tabela membro. Eu busco a tabela membro pelo ID e através dela eu consigo capturar os outros valores desse registro e pegar eles e gravarem na tabela grandeComissão assim no postman.

**post**  localhost:8080/grande_comissao/1

```
{
    "codigo": 1,
    "nome": "Paulo cesar",
    "voto": 1
}
```

O que acontece é que ele fica sobrescrevendo. Eu não consigo salvar os três registros

```
localhost:8080/grande_comissao/2
localhost:8080/grande_comissao/3
```

O resultado vai ser esse ao realizar uma consulta **GET**.

```
{
    "codigo": 1,
    "nome": "Paulo gilson",
    "voto": 1
}
```

O resultado esperado deveria ser esse abaixo ao realizar uma consulta **GET**

```
[
    {
    "codigo": 1,
    "nome": "Paulo cesar",
    "voto": 1
    },
   {
    "codigo": 2,
    "nome": "Paulo testa",
    "voto": 1
   },
    {
        "codigo": 3,
        "nome": "Paulo gilson",
        "voto": 1
    }
]
```

Eu preciso de ajuda para alterar o algoritmo responsável em realizar a gravação desses registros, pois não deveria está sobrescrevendo, alguém teria uma ideia de como corrigir o código abaixo.

```
@PostMapping("/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<GrandeComissao> buscarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
    Optional<Membro> membro = this.membroRepository.findById(codigo);
    grandeComissao.setNome(membro.get().getNome());
    grandeComissao.setVoto(1);
    grandeComissaoRepository.save(grandeComissao);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(grandeComissao);
}
```

Estou aberto a perguntas!

Essa é minha classe controle

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/grande_comissao")
public class GrandeComissaoResource {
    
    @Autowired
    private MembroRepository membroRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GrandeComissaoRepository grandeComissaoRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
    

    GrandeComissao grandeComissao = new GrandeComissao();

    GrandeComissao grandeComissaoSalva = new GrandeComissao();
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<GrandeComissao> listar() {
        return grandeComissaoRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/{codigo}")
    public ResponseEntity<GrandeComissao> buscarPeloCodigo(Long codigo) {
        Long id = codigo;
        Optional<Membro> membro = this.membroRepository.findById(id);
        grandeComissao.setNome(membro.get().getNome());
        grandeComissao.setVoto(1);
        grandeComissaoRepository.save(grandeComissao);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(grandeComissao);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certifique-se de que o registro que está indo para o método save, esteja sem identificador pois se ele está sobrescrevendo provavelmente o objeto que está chegando está com um identificador

Retire -> GrandeComissao grandeComissao = new GrandeComissao(); de atributo da classe e coloque-o dentro do método

Assim:

```
@PostMapping("/{codigo}")
    public ResponseEntity<GrandeComissao> buscarPeloCodigo(Long codigo) {
        Long id = codigo;
        Optional<Membro> membro = this.membroRepository.findById(id);
        GrandeComissao grandeComissao = new GrandeComissao();
        grandeComissao.setNome(membro.get().getNome());
        grandeComissao.setVoto(1);
        grandeComissaoRepository.save(grandeComissao);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(grandeComissao);
    }
```

Dessa forma você terá certeza de que toda vez que houver uma requisição nesse endpoint, será criado um objeto **grandeComissao** diferente para cada requisição

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o seguinte:
Copie o trecho GrandeComissao grandeComissao = new GrandeComissao();
que vc declarou de forma global e cole na primeira linha do método buscarPeloCodigo;

Como vc declarou o objeto de forma global, quando ele passa pelo save é automaticamento injetado um id nele, quando vc chama pela segunda vez já deve ter um id lá, portanto a partir daí a aplicação fica dando updates ao invés de inserts.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).